# Eddystone notification on android

Tags: eddystone

I tried getting the notification on ios when eddystone url is broadcasted from a beacon.In Android, i came to know it will be available with Google Play services 7.8 version onwards. My android phone is upgraded with this version, but still iam not getting notification, is there any setting to be done?

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure that the beacon is broadcasting the URL you expect by using an off-the-shelf beacon detector like [Locate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en), which will decode Eddystone-URL transmissions.

If you are still having trouble, an alternative to using Google Play Services 7.8 is to use the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html) (upon which the above Locate app is based).  You can find sample code showing how to detect and decode Eddystone-URL transmissions under the "Working With Eddystone URL" section here:  http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-how-to.html

Answer (score 0):

To have a notification you should have an app listening to the beacon. It's not very clear, but right now only chrome for ios is listening and showing the beacons at "today" widget.

Google services has methods to listen for beacons, but you have to implement in your own app or use one from google play. The ones that are available right now however, don't run as a service and you have to open the app explicitly.

Comment: Chrome for Android is supposed to work now, but I've had a lot of trouble getting any notification